# using normal distribution and CSV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .csv file with mean and standard deviation for each person. I have created a function which reads the file and creates a dictionary.

```
def read_data():
    f = open("data.csv","r")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data[row[0]] = (float(row[1]),float(row[2]))
    return data
```

The output of this is

```
{'Person 1': (50.0, 0.0), 'Person 2': (100.0, 10.0), 'Person 3': (100.0, 5.0)}
```

I want to write a function which takes the mean and standard deviation for each person and generates a random number using normal distribution. I would like the output to be something like

```
{'Person 1': (*random number*), 'Person 2': (*random number*), 'Person 3': (*random number*)}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try something? What exactly is the problem? Take a look at the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module, you can use the `gauss` function.

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit?  Do you want the random number to be between the mean and 1, 2 or some increment of the standard deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random.gauss`. Given a mean and standard deviation for a person, you create a random value based on a normal distribution as follows

```
from random import gauss

data = {'Person 1': (50.0, 0.0), 'Person 2': (100.0, 10.0), 'Person 3': (100.0, 5.0)}
# Randomize values based on a normal distribution
rand_data = {k: gauss(mu=v[0], sigma=v[1]) for k,v in data.items()} 

# mu specifies mean and sigma specifies standard deviation
```

Alternatively, if you already plan on using `numpy`, can use `numpy.random.normal`:

```
from numpy.random import normal

data = {'Person 1': (50.0, 0.0), 'Person 2': (100.0, 10.0), 'Person 3': (100.0, 5.0)}
# Randomize values based on a normal distribution
rand_data = {k: normal(loc=v[0], scale=v[1]) for k,v in data.items()} 

# loc specifies mean and scale specifies standard deviation
```

The result of each gives the following running Python 3.7:

```
{'Person 1': 50.0, 'Person 2': 104.66767928603309, 'Person 3': 90.49432247610861}
```

Comment: Using `numpy` is not really necessary here.

Comment: `random.gauss` from the standard library - it's not really "better", but it means one less dependency to install, and numpy can take quite long to import. Its benefits are not really used here.

Comment: Just realized after posting. Thanks. Updated.